# Can someone define questions that are "not useful"?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Can someone define a bad question especially a question that is "not useful"?

Comment: We're missing some context here. There is no close reason for unusefulness, as far as I know, so I don't see where this term comes from.

Comment: if you hover over the downvote button here the reasons given are not well "researched", "unclear", or "unuseful"

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/205264

Answer (score 1):

> It's localized (will probably be useless to the world)

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130054/205264) general SE page